# Limit of matrix powers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an arbitrary matrix $A$ with eigenvalues within the unit circle. Is there a nice formula for $A^\infty = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n$?

In particular, maybe there is a formula which involves the three matrices from the SVD of A?

I am asking this from an algorithmic standpoint, i.e. is there a better way to compute $A^\infty$ than simply squaring the matrix $A$ many times?

Comment: That depends. Is it a matrix of which the columns add up to 1? In that case, the limit can be easily verified. Otherwise diagonalization could be an option.

Comment: No formula I am aware of. If all eigenvalues are in the unit circle, there exists a submultiplicative norm such that $\|A\|<1$, but this doesn't really help. The Jordan form shows the result too. The SVD can be arbitrarily large while having all eigenvalues be zero, so it is unlikely to help.

Comment: As an aside, the SIAM Review article by Moler & Van Loan  "Nineteen Dubious Ways to
Compute the Exponential of a
Matrix, Twenty-Five Years
Later" is a good read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** You may use eigendecomposition. Let $A=PJP^{-1}$ where $J=J_{r_1}(\lambda_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus J_{r_s}(\lambda_s)$ is the Jordan form of $A$ and each $J_{r_i}(\lambda_i)$ is a Jordan block of size $r_i$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Clearly, $A^m$ converges if and only if $J_{r_i}(\lambda_i)^m$ converges.

Now, consider a Jordan block $B=J_r(\lambda)$.

1. If $|\lambda|\ge1$ and $\lambda\neq1$, the diagonal entries of $B^m$, which are equal to $\lambda^m$, do not converge.
2. If $\lambda=1$ and $B$ is a nontrivial Jordan block ($r>1$), the diagonal entries of the superdiagonal of $B^m$, which are equal to $m$, diverge.
3. If $B$ is a $1\times1$ Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, clearly $B^m=1$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}B^m=1$.
4. If $|\lambda|<1$, consider $DBD^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the form $\operatorname{diag}(\varepsilon,\varepsilon^2,\ldots,\varepsilon^n)$ with $\varepsilon>0$. $B^m$ converges if and only if $(DBD^{-1})^m$ converges. However, the effect of the conjugation $B\mapsto DBD^{-1}$ is to scale the superdiagonal of $B$ by $\varepsilon$. Therefore, when $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small, the maximum row sum norm of $DBD^{-1}$, $\|DBD^{-1}\|_\infty$, is strictly smaller than $1$. Hence $C^m$ and in turn $B^m$ converge to $0$.

Therefore, for any $n\times n$ complex matrix $A$,

> $A^m$ converges if and only if the Jordan decomposition of $A$ has the form $P(J_{r_1}(\lambda_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus J_{r_t}(\lambda_t)\oplus I)P^{-1}$, where $|\lambda_1|,\ldots,|\lambda_t|<1$ (the identity block $I$ is void if $r_1+\cdots+r_t=n$). If this is the case, $\lim_{m\to\infty}A^m=P(0\oplus I)P^{-1}$. In particular, if all eigenvalues of $A$ lie inside the *open* unit disc, $\lim_{m\to\infty}A^m=0$.

If $A$ is real, since $\lim_{m\to\infty}A^m=X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\lim_{m\to\infty}A^m=X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, the above argument still applies and $P(0\oplus I)P^{-1}$ is real (given that $A^m$ converges) despite $P$ may be complex.

Comment: Do you have a reference, or is this obvious?

Comment: I think the conclusion is obvious enough, but I don't have any reference at hand, so I have added more details to the answer.